# Reading .txt into Julia DataFrame as Date Type

Tags: dataframe, julia

Is there way to read date ("2000-01") variables from text files into a Julia DataFrame directly, as a date? There's no documentation on this from what I have seen.

```
df = readtable("path/dates.txt", eltypes = [Date, Date])
```

This doesn't work, even though it seems like it should. My usual process is to read the dates in as strings and then loop over each row to create a new date variable. This has become a bottleneck in some of my processes now, do to the size of the  DataFrames.

My usual flow is to do something like this:

```
full_df[:real_date] = Date(full_df[:temp_dte_string], "m/d/y")
```

Thank you

Comment: Also, I would be interested in what people think is the best way to drop a variable from a DataFrame is. I tend to use delete!(DataFrame, Variable)

Comment: You could certainly read the file in line by line and construct a DataFrame that way. There are many DataFrame constructors. I think a dictionary of column name to list will do the trick. Be aware readlines() won't work above a certain size (which is a function of your RAM I'd imagine) so when I do something like this I use a while loop and go line by line although batches could be faster. I've noticed for whatever reason there is some overhead constructing date and datetime objects so be aware if your files are huge.

Comment: Regarding deleting a variable. you could always subset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's currently any way to do the loading in a single step like your first suggested code.  However you can speed up the second method somewhat by making a DateFormat object and calling Date with that instead of with a string.
(This is mentioned briefly [here](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/dates/).)

```
dfmt = Dates.DateFormat(“m/d/y”)
full_df[:real_date] = Date(full_df[:temp_dte_string], dfmt)
```

(For some reason I thought Date was not vectorized and have been doing this inside a for loop in all my code.  Whoops.)

By delete a variable do you mean delete a column or a row?  If you mean the former, then there's a few other ways to do this including things like

```
function vectorin(a, b) #IMHO this should be in base
    bset = Set(b)
    [i in bset for i in a]
end
df = DataFrame(A1="", A2="", A3="", D="", E="", F="") #Some long list of columns 
badCols = [:D, :F] #Some long list of columns you want to remove
df = df[names(df)[!vectorin(names(df), badCols)]]
```

Sometimes I read in csv files with a lot of extra columns, then just do something like

```
df = readtable("data.csv")
df = df[[:Only, :the, :cols, :I, :want]]
```